# How do you shuffle values from ng-repeat? (AngularJS)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, list, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc3YH/3/) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804487/angularjs-shuffle-and-limitto-a-list), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4qLzv/), [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101989/using-angularjs-how-could-i-randomize-the-order-of-a-collection), and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/owenmead/fa4v8/1/).

I still can't make `shuffle` or `random` work on my end. My code has stopped here:

```
signupApp.filter('shuffle', function() {
var shuffledArr = [],
  shuffledLength = 0;
return function(arr) {
  if (!arr || !arr.length) { return; }
  var o = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
  if (shuffledLength == arr.length) return shuffledArr;
  for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  shuffledArr = o;
  shuffledLength = o.length;
  return arr.slice(o);
  };
});
```

**my ng-repeat**

```
<ul ng-repeat="codes in response | shuffle">
  <li ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
    <strong>{{codes.id}}</strong> 
    {{codes.code}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Results still do not randomize my outputs. Can someone help?

[UPDATE]: My code works in randomizing ng-repeat:

```
<span ng-repeat="codes in response">
  <strong ng-if="((codes.branch == formData.branches.alias) && (codes.taken == 0))">
  {{codes.code}}
  </strong>
</span>
```

When `limitTo:1` is added, it no longer displays anything. In my controller, the fisher-yates is run like this:

```
var shuffleArray = function(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle
    while (m) {
        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }

    return array;
    }

    http.get("server/fetch.php").success(function(response){
    scope.response = response;
    shuffleArray(scope.response);
  }).error(function() {
    scope.response = "error in fetching data";
  });
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. When `limitTo:` is set to 6, it outputs a single random value from the list. I also tried to set it to 10, and it outputs two random values from the list. I'm confused. I just want to limit it to 1 and randomize it.

Comment: How do I use this on my code?

Comment: You should never return a new reference from a filter everytime that its called.  This will result in an infinite digest and break your code. Instead try to modify the existing array and return that (array.slice creates a new array)

Comment: I updated my question @pixelbits. Please see above.